# How to return a List, after a Method fills it, Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm stuck with a problem and I wondered if you can help me.

I have a functions (in Flutter) that returns a List of Items. Now this List of Items should be Filled by an other function, which goes thought my Database and collect the right items. My Problem is, that my Function runs after the Return Statement... Here is some Code:

```
Future<List<MaterialItem>> getItems(String path, String fach) async {


// This is a empty List that I want to fill
List<MaterialItem> list = [];

// That's my Function, that fills the List
var result = await _db
    .collection("$path/$fach/")
    .get()
    .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
    
    // Here the List gets filled
    list.add(MaterialItem.fromSnapshot(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  });
});

// Here the List should be returned, but after my Function fills it.
return list;


}
```

Hope you know what my problem is, and someone can help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could solve this using a `Completer`. Your function should return the Future property of the `Completer` and the database call should then complete it.

Take a look at the API and the example:
https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.12.4/dart-async/Completer-class.html

For example: (pseudo code)

```dart
Future<List<MaterialItem>> getItems(String path, String fach) async {
  
  // declare a completer
  Completer<List<MaterialItem>> completer = Completer();
  List<MaterialItem> list = [];
  final result = await _db
      .collection("$path/$fach/")
      .get()
      .then((QuerySnapshot querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.docs.forEach((doc) {
      
      list.add(MaterialItem.fromSnapshot(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
    });
    
    // let the database call complete the completer
    completer.complete(list);
  });

  // return the future value of the completer
  return completer.future;
}
```

Comment: How would you implement that?

Comment: I added an example.